# Getting the value of an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working good thanks to the help of members here. Now I have one last step / request. I have the following code that some may have seen before just in the last hour:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^=topic]").change(function () {
            var a = 'pk' + $(this).attr('id').replace('topic', '');
            var b = $(a).val()
            alert(b);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and then later on:

```
<td id='pk_1'>Cat</td>
<td id='pk_2'>Dog</td>
```

This code picks out pk_1, pk_2 etc and places into the variable named "a". What I would like is not to get the value of the element pk_1. I tried some different ways of getting this and putting into "b". For example I added "#". None work. Sometimes the alert box shows the word "undefined" sometime nothing. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you all

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()`:

```
...
var a = '#pk' + $(this).attr('id').replace('topic', '');
var b = $(a).html();
alert(b);
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks it works. It said "I can accept the answer in 9 minutes". Please wait and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=topic]").change(function () {
        var a = '#pk_' + $(this).attr('id').replace('topic', ''); //add # and _
        var b = $(a).html(); //use .html and not .val
        alert(b);
    });
})
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an id the selector should start with `#`.  Prepend that to the selector.    Also, a `td` element doesn't have a `value`, only `input` elements do.  You probably want the inner `text` (or, perhaps, the `html`). If that's not working, then check that the ids are what you expect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^=topic]").change(function () {
            var a = '#pk' + $(this).attr('id').replace('topic', '');
            var b = $(a).text()
            alert(a + ' has value ' + b);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Overall this answer is really good, but I think val() should be reserved for input elements

Comment: Thats bizzarre, I could've sworn you had var b = $(a).val(); not .text(). My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that a very specific id, say id='topic_1' corresponds to exactly id='pk_1', I would say that you should be skipping over the whole replacing/manipulating id tags to find another.

Instead use the metadata plugin.

```
<input type=text id="topic1" class="topic {pk:#pk_1}"/>
<input type=text id="topic2" class="topic {pk:#pk_2}"/>
```

In script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".topic").change(function () {
        alert($($(this).metadata().pk).html());
    }
}
```

metadata can be downloaded here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out. It looks like it could be even better.

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong with the other method, and I use it occasionally, but I am a bit funny about accessing objects based on the manipulation of other names.